Cannot update packages on Debian Trixie due to an error
I have encountered an error when updating my packages on Debian Trixie and couldn't solve it.
The sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade outputs this:
After this operation, 2,769 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libgphoto2-l10n.
(Reading database ... 332236 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgphoto2-l10n_2.5.31-2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgphoto2-l10n (2.5.31-2.1) ...
Setting up libuim-data (1:1.8.8-9.4) ...
uim-module-manager: symbol lookup error: uim-module-manager: undefined symbol: u
im_internal_strlcpy
dpkg: error processing package libuim-data (--configure):
 installed libuim-data package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 127
Setting up libgphoto2-l10n (2.5.31-2.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uim-data:
 uim-data depends on libuim-data (>= 1:1.8.8-9.4); however:
  Package libuim-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package uim-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libuim-data
 uim-data
======  How can you help?  (doc: https://wiki.debian.org/how-can-i-help ) ======

-----  Show old opportunities as well as new ones: how-can-i-help --old  -----
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have tried sudo apt autoremove but it did not help
I understand that I'm having issues with packages "libuim-data" and "uim-data" but don't know what to do with it.
I noticed that reinstalling package "libuim-data" would affect a lot of packages that depend on it. Thus, I didn't want to make a mistake, so I decided to ask here first. Can anybody help?
UPD1 ==> apt policy uim libuim8 outputs:
uim:
  Installed: 1:1.8.8-9.2+b3
  Candidate: 1:1.8.8-9.4+b1
  Version table:
     1:1.8.8-9.4+b1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:1.8.8-9.2+b3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libuim8:
  Installed: 1:1.8.8-9.4+b1
  Candidate: 1:1.8.8-9.4+b1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.8.8-9.4+b1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


This is normal. Debian Trixie is a future release that is still in testing. One will run into things such as issues with installing packages, performing upgrades, etc.

@NasirRiley hopefully. Though, I haven't updated my packages in a while, I thought it might be on me.

i've used synaptic to remove broken packages one by one revising what will be removed as dependency, and than done a apt-get full-upgrade. all works fine now

You need to upgrade uim:
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends uim

Currently the main package and its library packages are mismatched, which prevents uim-module-manager from running. libuim-data relies on that for its own setup, and fails as a result.
